# Why is an element in my Python list being skipped?

Tags: python

I'm creating a program to categorize arguments that I give it in the form of a list. Right now, an "option" is an argument that is immediately after an argument that starts with `-`. A "switch" is an argument that starts with `--`. Here's my whole program:

```py
args = ['--encrypt', '-e', 'encryption', '-c', 'ceaser']
options = []
switches = []

def categoriseArgs():
    global args, options, switches
    for arg in args:
        if arg.startswith('--'):
            switches.append(arg)
            del args[args.index(arg)]

        elif arg.startswith('-'):
            option = args[args.index(arg) + 1]
            index = args.index(arg)
            options.append(option)
            del args[index]
            del args[index]
        

categoriseArgs()
print(args)
print(options)
print(switches)
```

For some reason, I get this output:

```
['-e', 'encryption']
['ceaser']
['--encrypt']
```

`'encryption'` needs to be part of `options` too. And there shouldn't be anything left in `args` because I delete the elements. I tried debugging this, and the program simply does not test `'-c'` and so it and the option after it are just ignored. Why exactly does this happen?

Comment: Because you're maipulating the list by removing items at the same time as you are iterating over it.

Comment: Because you are removing items from your list as you iterate over it. Don't do that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [(Unintentionally) skipping items when iterating over a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513531/unintentionally-skipping-items-when-iterating-over-a-list)

Comment: Don't do this kind of argument parsing yourself. Look at module `argparse`.

Comment: @BoarGules I find ArgParse to complicated in my program.

Comment: And thanks! I understand the skipping now, deleting an item messes with the next element to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can track what you have already seen

```
args = ['--encrypt', '-e', 'encryption', '-c', 'ceaser']
options = []
switches = []
wasLastStartingWithSomething = False #Track what you have already seen
def categoriseArgs():
    global args, options, switches, wasLastStartingWithSomething
    for arg in args:
        if arg.startswith('--'):
            switches.append(arg)
            wasLastStartingWithSomething = False
        elif arg.startswith('-'):
            wasLastStartingWithSomething=True
        elif wasLastStartingWithSomething:
            options.append(arg)
    args = []

categoriseArgs()
print(args)
print(options)
print(switches)
```

```
[]
['encryption', 'ceaser']
['--encrypt']
```

Recommended: This is tested on what is given in the question by OP! It is advised you test it for more inputs

Also since lists are mutable, you can pass them as arguments to your function! `def categoriseArgs(args, options, switches, wasLastStartingWithSomething):`

Also args is a special name, *args in function definitions in python is used to pass a variable number of arguments to a function.

```
def myFun(*args): 
    for arg in args: 
        print (arg)
   
myFun('Hello', 'Welcome', 'to', 'StackOverFlow')
```

```
Hello
Welcome
to
StackOverFlow
```

Comment: Perfect, it works! It's also more efficient. Thank you.

Comment: @SkyPlayX I am glad I was able to help! Happy coding!